# From Address for outbound email message in communities

Tags: community, email, community-builder

We have a requirement to set the **from address to the outbound emails sending from communities like welcome, forgot password and reset password**.

Currently it's taking the email address which we provided in the community administration page.

One solution i thought for this is configuring **org-wide email addresses**, but it's not working.

Apart from this is there any solution or am i missing anything configuring for org wide email addresses

Any Suggestion/Solution are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What didn't work with org-wide email address? I apologize in advance for mentioning something that may be obvious, but did you verify the org-wide address?

Comment: @shmuels, Verified the org wide email address and assigned for the community user profile as well, but still community email is set as the from address for outbound emails

Comment: Great. Where are you sending these emails from (i.e. apex, lightning quick action, record page)?. You will need to select the org-wide address, as the 'From' address, in the compose email window. It won't automatically be selected; there should be a drop-down where you can select the current user's email or the org-wide address.

Comment: @shmuels, we are not sending the emails, the email send logic is handled by salesforce, like when the community user is created based on the checkbox in community welcome email will be sent to the user, same thing with the forgot and reset password we can only configure the email templates.

Comment: 'email send logic is handled by salesforce'...
Using what? Process Builder and Email Alerts?